# Spring Boot : how to call "postProcessBeanFactory" and get the desired beans

Tags: java, spring-boot, javabeans

I am trying to use `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` for creating multiple beans dynamically at run time. But somehow it is not getting called and I am not able to figure out how to get the beans from beanFactory when i need to use it.

Added below in `JavaBeanConfig` file for bean creation :

```
@Bean
public static BeanFactoryPostProcessor beanFactoryPostProcessor() {
   return new CBProviderConfig();
}
```

Below is the `CBProviderConfig` which is intend to use for bean creation dynamically.

```java
@Configuration
public class CBProviderConfig implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {

    @Value("${couchbase.bucketCount}")
    int bucketCount;

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        for (int index = 0; index < bucketCount; index++) {
            System.out.println("register my bean: " + index);

            beanFactory.registerSingleton("cbProvider" + index, new CouchbaseDTOProvider("cbProvider" + index));
        }
    }
}
```

Now my question is how can I access the beans which are created in `CBProviderConfig`!!

Comment: You cannot use placeholders in the `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` as those are being processed by another `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` so that won't work, the value when being called will be `0` as nothing has been replaced yet. You should also remove the `@Configuration` as it shouldn't be detected and should only be constructed by the `public static` method.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks it worked. I initialized `bucketCount` with value 3 and removed `@Configuration` . Now beans are getting registered. I want to call a method marked with `@PostConstruct` for each of these beans. Is there anyway I can do this ??

Comment: Spring will do that, just don't use `registerSingleton`. Instead of implementing `postProcessBeanFactory` implement `postProcessBeanRegistry` and register a `BeanDefinition` instead of an instance. This will let Spring fully control your object and all the normal Spring initializing etc. will be applied automatically.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for you suggestion. But there is no method called `postProcessBeanRegistry` in `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` interface. Are you suggesting to use any other interface !! ?
I googled `postProcessBeanRegistry` but did not get information around it. Could you please elaborate a bit more.

Comment: My bad the method is `postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry` (which you would have seen in your tooling).